# Perturbed hydrogen atom transition probabilities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, commutator, perturbation-theory, hydrogen

> Given the perturbed hydrogen atom having Hamiltonian
>
> $$ \hat{H} = \frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{|\vec{r}|}+\lambda \vec{S}\cdot \vec{r} $$
>
> (1) say which operators commute with the Hamiltonian among
> $\{\vec{S}^2, \vec{L}^2, \vec{J}^2, J_z, \Pi\}$
>
> (2) Labelling a state like $|n, l, l_z, s_z>$, show that
>
> $$ <2, 1, 1, -\frac{1}{2}|\vec{S}\cdot\vec{r}|1, 0, 0,\frac{1}{2}>+\sqrt{2}<2, 1, 0, \frac{1}{2}|\vec{S}\cdot\vec{r}|1, 0, 0,\frac{1}{2}> =0$$

**My attempt**

(1) The unperturbed part of the Hamiltonian commutes with all the operators, so I only need to check which ones commute with the perturbation. Since $[S^2, S_i] = 0$ and $[r_i, S_j] = 0$, $S^2$ is conserved. $L^2$, $J^2$ and $J_z$ all have non-zero commutators with $r_i$ therefore these quantities shouldn't be conserved. Finally $\Pi$ commutes with $S_i$ but anti-commutes with $r_i$, therefore parity is also not conserved.

(2) I would say the first commutator is zero because the spin should be conserved, therefore there can't be a transition between $|\frac{1}{2}>$ and $-|\frac{1}{2}>$ (EDIT: this is wrong, $S^2$ is conserved but $S_i$ is not). I have no idea how to prove that the second bre-ket is zero.

If I have to guess, I would say that I was wrong somewhere and one more operator is actually conserved, so the bra-ket actually violates some conservation, although doing the commutators one by one (which I avoided to keep it short and clean) this doesn't seem to be the case.

**So my questions are**

Is it true that only $S^2$ is conserved? Is there a quicker way to do this commutators rather than actually decomposing everything down to the canonical commutators, maybe based on physical considerations? How do we prove the second bra-ket is zero?

Thanks!